# How to print the output of while loop in one line in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop

It is a program to take input from user and print that iput in one line.
when the user gives input 1,2,3,4
the output that is every number come out in different line.

that is after each iteration of loop output comes in new line but i want output to be in single line.How can i do it?
but i want output
1 2 3 4 5 
how to get that output

```
print("Program to print a 1d array")
array=[]
i=0
j=0
while(i<5):               ##whileloop1
    item=int(input())
    array.append(item)
    i=i+1
while(j<5):              ##whileloop2
    print(array[j])
    j=j+1
```

Comment: In Python 3: `print(array[j], end=' ')`, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print).

Comment: Should your second while loop be indented so it's inside the first?

Comment: @ohruunuruus no that would throw an out of bounds exception

Comment: @JGerulskis looking more closely I see what's going on. I thought nested while loops were used to print an array

Comment: As a side note, this is not a good way to loop over a list. Just do `for item in array:`. And for the first loop, `for j in range(5):`.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `join`:

```
print("Program to print a 1d array")
array = [int(input()) for _ in range(5)]
print(' '.join(map(str, array)))
```

Comment: up voted because of the improvement on OP code

Answer (score 0):

As @Bo102010 said, "In Python 3: `print(array[j], end=' ')`". But alternatively python supports printing lists as is. `print(list)` ,or in you case, `print(array)` will print out an array on one line.

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> print(*array)
42 23 -17 0 99999
```

Comment: Why the downvote? Aren't we allowed to offer perfectly valid better solutions to the problem the OP actually is trying to solve? If *I* were asking such a question, I'd be happy to be told I'm doing it wrong and be shown a better way.